# Want to save Correlated variable locally in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I want to save correlated variable locally (localdrive) then i might need to edit that variable with other dynamic value and then i should send it to subsequent request in Jmeter.
Please suggest me a way to perform the same.

Comment: Any news on that ? If answer is ok you are supposed to accept it so that others can use it

Answer (score 2):

Correlation in JMeter works as follow:

- Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) on the sampler that contains the data you want to extract, example:

[image]

- JMeter will automatically add a variable QUANTITY that will contain the extracted data
- If you want to modify the variable you will use a [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- In the next sampler you can use the data as ${QUANTITY}

No need to store anything on disk.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.Can you please explainm with an example.